# Laravel, Openshift, and error messages

Tags: laravel, debugging, error-handling, openshift

I have just created an app on Openshift and been making modifiactions. I test them locally before pushing the modifications. I now have an error that does not appear locally so I need to have details about the error.

How do I get the messages to display?

Comment: On OpenShift, you can ssh into your app and find logs in `~/app-root/logs/`. The same logs would be in `~/app-root/repo/storage/logs/` if using the community developed [Laravel 5.0 quickstart](https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel). More about logs on OpenShift can be found in [this article](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/log-files.html).

Answer (score 0):

First step check your log files for getting all detailed information about your errors, if you use laravel it will be here **/storage/logs/**.